# How to htaccess redirect from domain/something to domain/something/ when something is a directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a testing domain let's say `http://example.com/`

Then I have a directory called "cd" like in `http://example.com/cd/` - this link works completly fine

However I also want to get the `http://example.com/cd` (without trailing slash link) to get working

I've searched a lot but didnt find any working solution, I came to this but it is till not working ...

**EDITED:**

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash On
RewriteRule ^/?cd(.*)$ /cd/$1 [R]
```

Any tips what am I doing wrong or how to do this ? :)

PS: The folder has a permission of 750 (Read&Execute by Owner&&Group) - but that shouldnt be a problem when redirecting should it be?

**EDIT:** Problem is that I always get the 403 Forbidden instead of the redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cd` is a real directory then you may have `DirectorySlash Off`.

Put this line on top of  your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` and `cd/.htaccess` files:

```
DirectorySlash On
```

Also remember that:

- you will need permissions 750 instead of 650 to make it work
- Add `DirectorySlash On` as first line on `cd/.htaccess`
- For security reasons also you should keep `DirectorySlash On` site wide.

Comment: If you use `DirectorySlash On` then both `/cd` and `/cd/` will work.

Comment: Try commenting out your existing rule. Is /cd a real directory?

Comment: Also you will need **permissions 750 instead of 650** to make it work.

Comment: Yes /cd is a real directory, changed to 750 still nothing, and also tried to comment the rules, .htaccess with only DirectorySlash On doesnt work anyway...

Comment: OK does /cd had any .htaccess by any chance?

Comment: well `/cd` contains its own .htaccess redirecting nice urls like (`/cd/register`) to real scripts like `/cd/register.php`

Comment: Aha my guess was right. Add `DirectorySlash On` as first line on `cd/.htaccess` and its permission should be 750.

Comment: Lol it finally works thank you so much ! :) - would you mind rewriting your comments as an anaswer edit please ? :)

Comment: You can write `domain/cd/gallery` to `domain/cd/gallery.php` even with  `DirectorySlash On`. Moreover for security reasons also you must keep `DirectorySlash On`. Sure I will add these comments in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn off `DirectorySlash` but doing so means that a request for `/cd` *will always show the contents of the directory* instead of the index file. That means you need to internally add the slash:

```
Options Indexes
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cd$ /cd/ [L]
```

Comment: still 403 Forbidden :(

Comment: @jave.web turn `Options Indexes` on in an htaccess file in the "cd" folder

Comment: @jave.web by adding `Options Indexes` to a line by itself